# Format full column to numeric using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am getting a string value from my DTO object.

```
Eg: String value = "123,90909.00"
```

I am writing this to an excel using Apache POI from a loop.

So I have a test column with this string values in my excel

Now I need to get the total of test column. So I am using logic as below in my loop

```
Sum = sum + value;
```

Now the sum i snot getting displayed correctly as I need to formay Test column as Number.

Can anyone help me how i can achieve this using Apache POI?

Can we set the full column format as number using Apache POI?

Code used:

```
                     for (TestDTO testDTO: dtoList) {
                         HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
                         Number n = fmt.parse(testDTO.getColumnValue());
                         writeBook(testDTO, row, sheet,workbook);                        
                         sum = sum + n.intValue();
                         fundName = testDTO.getFundName();
                         sumRowCount = rowCount;
                     }




  private static void writeBook(TestDTO testDTO, HSSFRow row, HSSFSheet sheet, HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(testDTO.getColumnValue());

}
```

I am looking to set the full column to numeric format. How can I achieve it? I need the column to be numeric with thousands separator and two decimal value

Comment: I can not understand the problem. Show some of your code.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs I have edited my initial posted and added the code in,

Comment: Create a cell style with the desired format, and apply that to the cells?